# I am facing an error when using the @login_required decorator, it shows TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/

Tags: python, django, authentication, decorator

I am trying to use login decorator in my project but when I use it it shows me the error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/

registration/login.html
```

urls.py

```
path('', login.login_view , name='login'),
path('fileupload/', FileUpload.fileup, name='fileupload'),
```

view.py->FileUpload.py->fileup

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def fileup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.user = request.user
            form.save()
            print(form.image)
            print(form.user_id)
            send_message(str(form.image), form.user_id)

            text_filename = 'media/' + str(form.image).rstrip('.jpg') + '.txt'
            form.text_file = text_filename
            print(str(form.text_file))
            form.save()
            with open(text_filename, 'r+') as file:
                new_text = file.read()

            return render(request, "pd/NewText.html", {
                'form': form,
                'new_text': new_text,
            })
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'pd/FileUpload.html', {'form': form})
```

I want if user has not signed in and try to access the url `fileupload\` then it not allow until he/she has not signed in.

Comment: Please post full stacktrace.

Comment: try this => `@login_required(login_url=reverse('login'))`

Comment: Is `django.contrib.auth` listed in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes it is listed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want.

```py
# Create your views here.
def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Succefully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)
```

[Here is the official doc so you can explore your options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model)

You don't need a decorator, just put in your view an if statement to check if the user is member or something else, if it's not then raise error.

[Also here is the Mozila Django Tutorial about creating login functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication#Setting_up_your_authentication_views)

Also make sure you have your templates in the right path.

Comment: It worked for raising the error. But if I don't want to raise error but instead I want to redirect to the login page and when the user login then the user is automatically directed to ```fileupload/```.

Comment: @Kartik well instead of raising an error you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect  Django redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Django is trying to redirect to the default login route, which is `/accounts/login`, see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#login-url). And the view behind that route needs a template.

The best approach IMO, in this case, is to change the settings to point to your login URL.

```
# settings.py
LOGIN_URL = "/"
```